# Error generating charts in crystal report viewer from java

Tags: java, charts, crystal-reports-xi

I have designed a report using crystal reports v14.1. The report contains some bar charts which are generated using data from MySQL database. All works well when I am previewing the report in the designer..

[image]

But when I am opening the same report in crystal report viewer from my program I am getting this error:

```
com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException: com/businessobjects/visualization/pfjgraphics/PFJSummaryInfo---- Error code:-2147467259 Error code name:failed
```

All my other reports are working fine. This is the first report containing charts. I have found same question on various websites but no solution to the error, particularly solution in java. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Please update your Libraries to include the missing jar file.

Latest version of JRC can be found at the below link

For more info:

https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-29757

Direct download link for JRC v12.2.220:

http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crystalreportsforeclipse/2_0/crjava-runtime_12.2.220.zip